# Why is every programming language "powerful"?

Tags: programming-languages

Every time I check out a web page dedicated to some programming language I always see the word *"powerful"* in the list of idiosyncrasies / attributes.

If every programming language is powerful why do they put that word in the tutorials / documentations?

Comment: A hammer is powerful.  More powerful in the hands of a skilled craftsman.  More powerful when used for its intended purpose.  As the sole tool to build a skyscraper...not so powerful.  Common sense no?

Comment: Do you think anyone would want to market their programming languaeg as "weak", "insipid", or "under-performing"?

Comment: Now that they got your attention, did you read more to find out how powerful?

Comment: @Frustrated, it would be nice if they were at least honest and were willing to point out the weaknesses in their language. Too often then claim to be the only hammer you'll need.

Comment: @Jeff O, yes I did...with the ones I was interested in (Java, PHP, Python)...and there are others to come.

Comment: Powerful is a very subjective category. One might sometimes be able to agree on one *core language* being more powerful than another one. E.g. C++ vs. C or VB6 vs Scala. If one includes the different use-cases, things are complicated again - like comparing apples to bananas.

Comment: If it's Turing complete you can solve any problem that can be solved on a Turing machine. Now that's a powerful language!

Comment: @FWFD: furthermore, the languages that *were* marketed like that are the ones whose web pages the OP never went to, because they didn't get enough traction to attract him. :-)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - did you never see the film "Crazy People"? - Could be a good strategy for the right language designer. Though, thinking about it, "Basic" already exists.

Comment: @awoodland - but Turing died in 1954 - his machine can't have been all that powerful...

Comment: @Steve314 Turing machine 2011 is packed with new features and *powerful* extensions to last year's model. The infinite tape is now twice as long too!

Comment: @awoodland - only *twice* as long? What about Moores law? The length should be around 275 Giga-infinities by now!

Comment: Regarding "market their programming languaeg as "weak"... well, there _is_ one product out there called Fawlty Language.  It's a freeware clone of ITT-VIS's IDL.

Comment: If you go to the supermarket and see a product labelled "Luxury <whatver>"... It isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't think of a language that was ever described as weak. Yes, I see it as marketing blurb, not only that, it places the onus for failure on the programmer rather than on the core capacities of the language. I mean, the language is powerful, so if there are problems with code it clearly cannot lie with the specifications for what is obviously an amazing language.

Thing is, if the next new language comes along does not describe itself as powerful, it will have an immediate disadvantage against previously existing competitors which do describe themselves as powerful. It's like an eternal circle now.

Comment: Ok, I see the point in your second paragraph. "if the next new language comes along does not describe itself as powerful, it will have an immediate disadvantage against previously existing competitors". So if a language misses this "feature" it is a disadvantage. You don't see my point though...I wasn't talking about weakness, I was talking about "powerful".

Comment: I do see your point. I think perhaps you don't see mine. The simple fact is attributes perceived as negative are never used. Ever. The opposite attribute is always used.

Comment: How about BASIC?

Answer (score 19):

Rule #207 of programming languages is that they're all good at some things (i.e., are powerful) and really suck at others.

The marketing material falls short in describing *where* the language it's pushing is powerful.  For example, Perl is great at text processing because it has some powerful features that make it easy to handle strings but is a real stinker for high-performance number crunching.  FORTRAN is the opposite.

Answer (score 13):

Because it's always true in some sense. One or more of these *powerful* aspects applies to all programming languages:

- Requires *powerful* computer to compile
- Only *powerful* brains can comprehend
- Old code has a *powerful*, overwhelming smell
- The license exerts *powerful* control over your budget
- Design goal originates from *powerful* drug visions
- Creates a *powerful* drive to adopt a different language

I'm sure I could go on, but I'm not even sure what *powerful* actually means. Is the language efficient, expressive, succinct, or what. Just another weasle word.

Comment: And I need powerful hands to crunch the installation disks. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to its use in sentences like "The X programming language is a powerful, succinct, elegant tool for doing Y and Z.", well, that's advertisement/propaganda. If you listen to all of them, all languages are powerful, all food is delicious, all cars are either family-friendly or cool/fast, all countries are righteous and heroic in a world of traitors and inhuman dictators, all religions are right, etc.

Like half of the other examples, it's not completely false but not even close to the whole truth - language A works well for tasks like X, language B works better for tasks like Y, both such at what the other is good at. (Sometimes, there are languages that *are* completely and utterly useless for practical purposes and only created and studied for comedy. These are esoteric languages and nobody writes serious propaganda for them.)

Comment: Well I know that it is propaganda, but I think that even the dumbest ones can spot this, so it may turn out to be reversed-propaganda. :)

Comment: I'd say the same about most advertisement, yet people who studied how to make money think it helps them make more money and spend tremedous sums on it. Similarily, people with an affinity for a certain language seem to think they have to shout out blatantly how incredibly great that language is. That includes it being powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Power is relative.  Every language is more powerful in some way than older languages.  Java is more powerful than C++ because it simplifies memory management.  C++ is more powerful than Java because it has template classes and functions and operator overloading and deterministic destruction.